# npm workspace command does not stop executing when command fails for a workspace

Tags: bash, npm, npm-workspaces

I have a bash script that runs test for all workspaces in npm. Here is the bash script:

```
  npm ci --no-optional;
  set -eE;
  npm run test; #test script in root package.json of workspace
```

Now in root `package.json` scripts, `test` runs `test` on all workspaces like this:
`"test": "npm run test -ws --if-present`

Problem:
I have workspace A, B, C and D. when the bash script runs and there is a failure or error when running test on workspace A, it continues on to running tests for B,C and D.

Solution asked for:
Stop executing as soon as there is a failure in workspace A and exit.

Things I have tried:
using trap to listen to ERR or EXIT and calling EXIT 1 within trap. It does not work.

Comment: I guess the `--if-present` flag assumes that any non-zero exit is due to the script not existing.

Comment: Hi @jonrsharpe. I removed `--if-present` arg and still ran into the same issue.

Comment: Does it exit non-zero _after_ running all of the tests, if any failed?

Comment: It returns a 0 exit code after running tests for all workspaces.

Comment: I've created an issue asking for an option to do that https://github.com/npm/rfcs/issues/602